# SQL MAx function with multiple columns showing in apex?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QatIL.png) [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb3qn.png)I am trying to write an sql function to show the year, playername, and ppg of the player with the highest ppg from each year in our database.

We have a Players table with all the stats, and a team table with stats linked to each season as a team total.

What I want to do is get the highest scorer from each season so:

```
2010: Jake 10ppg
2011: Jake 12 ppg
2012 Carl 13 ppq
```

Etc.

here is my current query

```
SELECT Year, PlayerName, MAX(PPG) AS PPG
FROM PLAYERS_T, TEAM_T
GROUP BY Year
ORDER BY PPG;
```

However this is not working, what do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags - please re-tag your question with the DBMS you're actually using.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but will show duplicated record if same PPG. *Dont know what is the use of Team table there*

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/POFF84157)**

```
WITH PLAYERS_T as (
     SELECT 2010 "Year",  'Jake' "PlayerName", 10 ppg     
     UNION 
     SELECT 2011 "Year",  'Jake' "PlayerName", 12 ppg     
     UNION 
     SELECT 2012 "Year",  'Carl' "PlayerName", 13 ppg     
)
 SELECT T1."Year", T1."PlayerName", T1.PPG
 FROM PLAYERS_T T1
 LEFT JOIN PLAYERS_T T2
   ON T1."Year" = T2."Year"
  AND T1.PPG <  T2.PPG
 WHERE T2."Year" IS NULL
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: ahh its working but not displaying anything, oh, this doesn't give the max PPG

Comment: Yes, my bad you need `LEFT JOIN` because  your data only have one row for year.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT players_T.playername, players_T.ppg, players_T.year
FROM
(SELECT year, MAX(PPG) AS mx
 FROM players_T
 GROUP BY year) sub
INNER JOIN players_T ON sub.mx = players_T.ppg
WHERE sub.year = players_T.year
ORDER BY players_T.year
```

In the subquery, this finds the max ppg per year. Then we join with the players table on the ppg to find the player name. The result should be the player name, ppg and year together. Let me know what you find!

**Edit: Need to include a WHERE clause for year**

Comment: Thank you so much, Right now the years aren't in order Do I just need ASC?

Comment: Not even - just order by should do it. See the update

Comment: question 2 If you know apex? haha how come when I try to plug this in then switch the ppq to rpg it tells me the year is an invalid identifier?

Comment: what's the exact error message? Is rpg just another column in players_T?

Comment: oh the years got switched to year_id, anyways the issue with rpg is that it is showing 2 for the year 2013. and likewise issues with the other columns im trying.

Comment: are they the same? the two for 2013?

Comment: trying to figure out how to add photos quick

Comment: no they are different players in 2013, I added an image to the main question

Comment: Try it with my edit - you might just need a distinct after SELECT. I am having trouble following without seeing players table

Comment: Yeah thats what we tried, we tried to put distinct before both years and it is still populating a year twice. Not sure why its populating years multiple times if its the same query and the original one is working?

Comment: I would have to see the players table to take a guess. Do you have a picture of that? Your image 1 isn't working btw...

Comment: the players table is like 90 entrys. but its come down to the image 1 let me update it I got the other 2 down to the image 1 issue by putting distinct by year

Comment: Actually now try it I forgot the year clause